# Does jsoup can work with localStorage values?

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying parse a website (f.e. google)
In Chrome local storage i see variables (key-value pairs)
And document content depends of this variables
Can i set it using jsoup?
Or I should use other tools for it?
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot access Chrome's content with your own code (unless you can find an exploit for that). You'll have to get the site's content with the proper `get` or `post` request made with jsoup and then parse the content by yourself. Just remember that jsoup only loads the HTML of the site, so if your content is loaded from JS, you'll have to find another way to get it.